# Get resource in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set the icon image of my JFrame. I can't figure out how to get the image file as a resource to be loaded using: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(URL);

I've heard of Class#getResource() but it won't work in my case as my file structure is:

```
com.faris.test.Test.class
com.faris.test.Test2.class
res.icon.png
```

My Test.class is the class that extends JFrame and is trying to fetch "icon.png", but I'm not sure how to get it as my class (Test.class) is in another folder. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what folder your class is in. You can just use: `Test.class.getResource("/res/icon.png");`.
Make sure to include the '/'
 at the beginning of the path.

Have you actually tried this?

Comment: Didn't work :/ Maybe my "res" folder isn't being compiled with IntelliJ? Do you know anything about IntelliJ and how to use res folders? I don't know myself, I just made a folder in my "src" folder called "res" and put icon.png in there...

Comment: Oh, no no no. That won't work, move the 'res' folder out of the 'src' folder into the project root. Is this being exported as an artifact?

Comment: Nope, just being compiled and run through IntelliJ. But 'aight I'll test that.

Edit: Still no...

Comment: Ok, if you exporting as an artifact later, remember you will have to include the 'res' folder in your JAR. (Make a new folder named 'res' in your JAR and  add the 'Directory Content' of the res folder into that folder)

Comment: This is my real file structure:
http://gyazo.com/7b76197a2e1806fde9a002793e5e9472


This is how I load it:


`URL iconURL = KingValidator.class.getResource("/res/16x16.png");

Image iconImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(iconURL);`

Comment: Question about what you said previously (the JAR thing): But wouldn't "Directory Content" put all the png's in the JAR, but not the actual "res" folder therefore typing getResource("/res/<x>.png") throw an error as "res" doesn't exist?

Comment: Never mind, you don't even have to use getResource(). Only use getResource() once you have exported it to a JAR. For now, you can just use `new File("res/16x16.png");`

And for your question, yes, that's why you must make a new folder named 'res' in your JAR first. (There is no option to put the actual directory in)

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll test getResource() when compiled as a JAR now.

Comment: Works when compiled! One more question: Is there a way to make it so that the "res" folder is compiled, and not just the contents of it? Currently I have to use KingValidator.class.getResource("/16x16.png") but I'd prefer all my resources to be in a "res" folder in the JAR...

Comment: I don't think that would be good practice (all the source is supposed to be in the src folder). However, it appears, any folders/files in the src folder are automatically compiled and put into the JAR so just move the 'res' folder back into the src folder. If you are worried about the resources being in the root of the JAR, just make a new folder for it (in this image: http://i.imgur.com/hWKkmsP.png) and drag the 'Directory Content of res' into the new folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured that I can still use getResource() for both JAR and compiling in IntelliJ by setting the "res" folder to a Resource in Modules -> Sources. This way, I don't need to add "Directory content" thing in the Artifacts as IntelliJ automatically adds the files into the JAR!

Comment: @FarisRehman if you want your source to be readily usable by other people follow the Maven Standard Directory Layout. Put java source in src/main/java, put production resources in src/main/resources, put test java source in src/test/java, and test resources on src/test/resources. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Using an external build tool like Gradle or Maven will help even more since they can use other IDEs.  Custom directory layouts and IDE-dependent build chains are a huge headache for programming on teams.

Comment: Thanks @AlainO'Dea for recommending this, I've used Maven for many of my projects before, but I just didn't think that Maven'd be suitable for my current project as it has no external dependencies. I may still convert my project into a Maven project, but I like how my project's working currently and Maven makes things initially complex.